# Not able to configure Selenium+Edge+Mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to setup Selenium to use with Python on a Mac BigSur, below are the steps I took for my current-fail config.

1. Install Selenium on my current python environment using `pip install selenium`
2. Downloaded MS Edge WebDriver that match my current Edge browser
3. Save the binary file on `/usr/local/bin` directory
4. Run `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` as suggested in the Selenium website under WebDrivers section
5. On my Jupyter notebook I have the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Edge
driver = Edge(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/msedgedriver')
```

6. When I run the cell I get the error:

```
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-eec278095d29> in <module>
      2 URL = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/watchlist/60321ee5b01cab343e1e37d6'
      3 
----> 4 driver = Edge(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/msedgedriver')
      5 
      6 # options = webdriver.edge()

...

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

7. Frustrated by ignorance ask help at SO

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I agree with art_architect's answer. You need to pass the capabilities to run the code on MAC OS. It seems that an empty one is enough. I also find [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259620/running-edge-browser-on-selenium-in-macos-catalina) with the same issue. You can also refer to it. Please try the solution and tell us about the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it wants some capabilities.
Can you try sending empty ones?

```
from selenium.webdriver import Edge

caps = {
}

driver = Edge(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/msedgedriver',capabilities=caps )
```

Comment: Thank you, my ignorance on the subject plus the half-baked tutorials I found online blocked me from moving forward

Comment: This `capabilities` are only mandatory for the Edge driver correct?

Comment: In theory they should be optional for all of them. But apparently not on mac os for edge ...