# MSEdgeDriver - session not created: No matching capabilities found error on Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Having some trouble getting our automation to run on Microsoft Edge. Have the correct browser version driver installed and have tried a few other 'fixes' to no avail. This is using Selenium with Python3 on PyCharm.

Going back to the beginning, this is my code...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='/Users/james.stott/PycharmProjects/venv/Selenium/Remote/msedgedriver')
```

And the following is the error raised...

*selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found*

Any help at all, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using Edge Chromium, you can refer to the steps below to automate Edge browser using Selenium python code:

1. Download and install the Python from this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. Launch the command prompt as an **Administrator**.
3. Run the command below to install the Edge Selenium tools.

   ```
   pip install msedge-selenium-tools selenium==3.141
   ```
4. Install the correct version of the Edge web driver from this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). (The WebDriver version should be the same as the Edge browser version)
5. Create a Python file using the code below and modify it as per your own requirements.

   ```
   from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

   options = EdgeOptions()
   options.use_chromium = True
   options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
   driver = Edge(executable_path = r"D:\selenium web drivers\edge driver\msedgedriver.exe", options = options) # Modify the path here...
   driver.get("https://example.com")
   ```

---

**Update:**

You need to send capabilities if you're using Mac OS. You can try to send an empty capability:

```
desired_cap={}

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='/Users/james.stott/PycharmProjects/venv/Selenium/Remote/msedgedriver', capabilities=desired_cap)
```

Comment: Same error occurs. No matching capabilities found

Comment: Which version of Edge browser and Edge WebDriver are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Edge
Version 89.0.774.50 (Official build) (64-bit)

EdgeDriver
Release 89
Version: 89.0.774.50

Comment: Are you using Mac OS? If so, you need to send capabilities. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259620/running-edge-browser-on-selenium-in-macos-catalina). I also edited my answer, you can check it.

Comment: That has worked now. thank you for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

For `linux` users using `executable_path` as `EdgeChromiumDriverManager` or any given path, follow the following snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install(), capabilities={"platform": "LINUX"})
```