# Edge browser driver does not launch in "Selenium"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I want to use Selenium to control the MS Edge browser.

However, I get an error and cannot move forward.

Please let me know the cause of this error and how to deal with it.

**# Information about the environment**

- **OS**: MacOS Big Sur / Ver. 11.2.3 (M1)
- **Computer language**: Python 3.6
- **Target browser**:Microsoft Edge / Ver.89.0.774.75
- **Installed webdriver**:I've already installed the appropriate one for the "Target
  browser".(URL:https://developer.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

**# Code**

*The commented-out "Chrome" will launch normally.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/yuchikawa/Dropbox/My Mac (YuのMacBook Pro)/Documents/scraping/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='/Users/yuchikawa/Dropbox/My Mac (YuのMacBook Pro)/Documents/scraping/msedgedriver')
```

**# Error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ae341505cdf7> in <module>
      4 #driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='/Users/yuchikawa/Dropbox/My Mac (YuのMacBook Pro)/Documents/scraping/msedgedriver')
      5 
----> 6 driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="/Users/yuchikawa/Dropbox/My Mac (YuのMacBook Pro)/Downloads/edgedriver_mac64 (1)/msedgedriver")

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/edge/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, capabilities, port, verbose, service_log_path, log_path, keep_alive)
     64                                               resolve_ip=False,
     65                                               keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 66             desired_capabilities=capabilities)
     67         self._is_remote = False
     68 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

Comment: Check here for similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092707/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send capabilities if you're using Mac OS. You can try to send an empty capability:

```
desired_cap={}

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='/Users/yuchikawa/Dropbox/My Mac (YuのMacBook Pro)/Documents/scraping/msedgedriver', capabilities=desired_cap)
```

There're threads with same issues:

[MSEdgeDriver - session not created: No matching capabilities found error on Selenium with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479396/msedgedriver-session-not-created-no-matching-capabilities-found-error-on-sele/66487791#66487791)

[Running Edge browser on Selenium in MacOs (Catalina)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259620/running-edge-browser-on-selenium-in-macos-catalina)

Comment: Thanks to you, the incident has been resolved !!